# Randomly fill a vector of vector with a fix number of elements

Tags: c++, random, vector

I have a project in wich I have to randomly fill a grid (`vector<vector<box>>`) with element, that have specific type, in each box.
 We have 4 specific types:`type1`,`type2`,`type3`, and `type4`.
The user sets the percent of each type.
Example :
Type1 33%, Type2 22%, Type3 22%, Type4 23%
We can have a grid like this :

```
\-----------
|1|1|3|3|4|2|
\-----------
|4|1|2|2|3|1|
\-----------
|4|4|2|1|1|3|
\------------
```

Here is the code I have :

```
<vector<vector<box>> grid;
//createGrid is a function initializing a grid with elements with neutral type.
//in this example the number of lines is 3 and the number of columns is 6
createGrid(grid,3,6);
double numberOfType1 = round (3*6*percentOfType1/100);
//each number is calculated in the same way 
vector<string> types={"Type1","Type2","Type3","Type4"}
for(int i=0,i<grid.size(),i++){
   for(int j=0,j<grid[i].size(),j++){
      int choice = rand()%types.size();
      if(types[choice]=="Type1"){
        grid[i][j]=Element("Type1");
        numberOfType1--;
        if(numberOfType1==0){
          //a function that delete the element by its value in the vector
          delete(types,"Type1"); 
        }
      }else if(types[choice]=="Type2"){
        grid[i][j]=Element("Type2");
        numberOfType2--;
        if(numberOfType2==0){
          delete (types,"Type2");
        }
      } //and so on
```

I know that I can use a switch case, but this is the first draft.
So my questions are:

1. is there an other better or easier way to do it ?
2. if not, can this be improved?

Comment: `delete(types,"Type1");` **`delete`** is a reserved keyword, you can't use it as a function name! Please give at least a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking about code. Also if this code is actually working, asking for improvement or review is off-topic for this site.

Comment: As @πάνταῥεῖ mentions, `delete` is a keyword. On top of that, `<vector<vector<box>> grid;` isn't even valid (that `<` at the front shouldn't be there). This code shouldn't even compile, let alone run.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean by "type."  Do you just want different values in the vector or should they actually be different types (via polymorphism)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion for the better/easier way to do it (requires C++11):

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::discrete_distribution<> d({3, 2, 2, 2});   //here determine discrete distribution

std::vector<int> v(10);   //or choose different size
std::generate(std::begin(v),std::end(v),[&](){return d(gen)+1;});
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08a4d96a2b9fcba7)

That produces a vector containing elements such as

```
4  2  1  2  3  3  2  1  3  1
```

Now just adjust this to the required types you wrote about.